# Spring Boot without EnableWebMvc gives EnabledHttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I am new to the Spring Boot ecosystem, and I noticed that if I don't use the *@EnableWebMvc* with my *@RestController*, I got an exception:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

I would like to know what does the annotation *@EnableWebMvc* do regarding the jackson serialization and/or how can avoid those exceptions without using the annotation.

Comment: can you show your pom. Try adding jackson dependency

Comment: add your main spring boot application class too or any relevant configurations. You should notneed the `@EnableWebMvc`